# How do I find an element in a list given a property of that element in java?

Tags: java, list

I have a list that contains names of colleges (strings). I have another list of Colleges, where each college has a String variable called "name". I want to match the names to colleges to each College object. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I think you forgot to include what you have tried so far.

Comment: [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html).

Answer (score 4):

With the [Stream API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/) introduced in Java 8, you can `filter(Predicate p)` the `College` list to produce a list of the `College` mentioned in the other list :

```
collegeList.stream()
           .filter(college -> collegeNamesList.contains(college.name))
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: @Aaron , can you explain your answer please ?

Comment: @Johnspecter I'm not sure I can actually : explaining the stream API is too broad for an SO answer, and I think someone familiar with it would understand my solution by reading my introductory sentence. I mentioned the Stream API and linked to an Oracle tutorial ; do you think that is enough? Would you suggest anything else?

Comment: @Aaron maybe you could put collegeNamesList into an HashSet to have better performances on contains

Comment: @NicolasFilotto it's an interesting suggestion but depending on the size of collegeNamesList the overhead of creating a HashSet may not be worth the reduced cost of access. I'm not going to edit my answer for the sake of brevity, but I hope anyone planning to use it will read your comment.

Comment: @Aron that's right, actually it depends on the size of both lists collegeNamesList and collegeList, if collegeNamesList is short and collegeList is big, it is still interesting